# Splitted input printing in Python [Python 3.4]

Tags: python, python-3.4

I am making a simple command line app, where one of the commands print the text you input after the word 'print'. The commands work fine and I'm using raw input. The commands, however, use a splitted input and extracting text from it is like using a table (string[num]). However, when execute the code, I get an error saying:

```
>>> 
:: print hello world
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Python34/Commands.py", line 10, in <module>
        for i in range(1, len(splitcmd-1)):
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'
>>>
```

The code I used is:

```
cmdlst = ['open', 'print', 'calculate']
files = ['Hello World', 'Hello Jeremy', 'Hello Dog']

while True:
    cmd = input(':: ')
    splitcmd = cmd.split()
    if  splitcmd[0] == 'open':
            print(files[int(splitcmd[1])])
    if splitcmd[0] == 'print':
        for i in range(1, len(splitcmd-1)):
            print(splitcmd[i], end = '')
            print('', end='\n')
```

I'm aiming to avoid using quotation marks in the command (''/""). Thanks for your help!

Comment: `split` returns an array. don't you want to get only the first part of tthe split? `splitcmd` is an array. you can't use arithmetic operators with `int` and `array`

Comment: Your parentheses are wrong, I think. Try `len(splitcmd)-1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change 
`for i in range(1, len(splitcmd-1)):` to

```
for i in range(1, len(splitcmd)-1):
```

Improper parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks! I don't notice the small things. I need to knuckle down and practice some debugging.

Comment: @iPhynx : could you please select it as an answer if it solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

You have the following error

```
for i in range(1, len(splitcmd-1)):
```

You should decrease 1 from the length not from the string:

```
for i in range(1, len(splitcmd)-1):
```

Comment: why add the exact same answer as before?

Comment: Didn't see it, when I wrote it

Answer (score 0):

I have to say that you codes aren't pythonic and when you use

```
:: open some_string_name
```

that will cause another problem.......if your some_string_name isn't a number. int() will take string-ed number, but not string.